# Count ssh find results

Tags: bash, ssh, scp, wc

I have this part in my script where I would copy 1 hour old files from one server to the current server I am currently logging in:

```
ssh testuser@sampleServer find /home/testuser/files -type f -mmin -60 > /home/user/bin/tmp/results.txt

while read LINE
do
    scp -r testuser@sampleServer:$LINE /home/user/bin/tmp
done < /home/user/bin/tmp/results.txt
```

I want to count the number of files retrieved in the first line of the code and store its value in a variable, so I just put:

```
COUNT=`ssh testuser@sampleServer find /home/testuser/files -type f -mmin -60 | wc -l`
```

But I believe this can still be improved, since it is redundant.
Do you have any suggestions as to how I can revise it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening *n*+1 TCP connections and performing SSH handshakes etc for each to copy *n* files seems horribly inefficient.

This is how you would usually do it (and also avoid that pesky temporary file):

```
ssh testuser@sampleServer '
    find /home/testuser/files -type f -mmin -60 -print0 |
    xargs -r0 tar zcf -' |
tar -C /home/user/bin/tmp -z -x -f -
```

This is assuming there are no newlines in any file names (which would have broken your original script as well) and that you don't mind creating a mirror directory structure in `/home/user/bin/tmp` if there is one on the remote site.

Now, adding a line count to your original script would have been simple -- why not run it on the temporary file?? -- but it can be similarly easy here.  Just add a `-v` option to the extracting `tar` filter and cound the number of output lines.

```
... | tar -C /home/user/bin/tmp -z -x -v -f - | wc -l
```

Comment: I'm very sorry sir, but it's not really clear to me. I'm still a newbie, I hope you understand.

Comment: We create a `tar` archive on standard output in the remote `ssh` session and extract the files from it at the other end of the pipeline.  This does the entire transaction with a single SSH session.

Comment: But so the minimal, unintrusive answer to your question would be `COUNT=$(wc -l </home/user/bin/tmp/results.txt)`

Comment: Ahh @tripleee I get it now. Thank you so much!

Comment: The `ssh` command will run in `/home/testuser` so you can do simply `cd files && find .`... to avoid printing the full directory path (and thus getting a copy of the tree structure at the destination).